# How to write a custom authorization implementation for Vert.x?

Tags: java, authorization, vert.x

I wrote a Java authorization library called jCasbin here: https://github.com/casbin/jcasbin. And I want to write a custom authorization plugin for Vert.x to use jCasbin as the authorization backend (determine whether to allow a request based on policy rules). But I don't know how to do it.

I saw Vert.x's documentation has such a page: https://vertx.io/docs/#authentication_and_authorisation. But all implementations provided there (like MongoDB auth, Shiro auth) contain both authentication and authorization. I only want to provide authorization. Is there a way to do it? What're the best steps?

Comment: But how can you envision the fact that would authorize "someone" to access resources `A`, `B`, ..., `N`, without knowing who is that "someone"? If you think about it, authentication may look like it's an independent concept, but it's somehow needed in order to have most of the authorization rules in place.

Comment: I know authorization needs the authenticated user name from authentication output. The step of injecting user name from authentication to authorization should be done by the Vert.x framework.

Answer (score 0):

In order to implement a `AuthZ` only provider you should have a look at the `JWT` provider: https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-auth/tree/master/vertx-auth-jwt

Remember that you should ignore the methods `generateToken` as those are helper to have `AuthN`.

So basically all you need to implement the following method:

```
@Override
public void authenticate(JsonObject authInfo,
                         Handler<AsyncResult<User>> resultHandler) {
  ...
}
```

The `authInfo` object should contain the token or whatever payload you need and then you will perform the assertions and if they are good return a `User` object.

The `User` objects will then be used to do the `AuthZ`. Your object should implement:

```
@Override
public void doIsPermitted(String permission,
                          Handler<AsyncResult<Boolean>> handler) {
  ...
}
```

For example see: https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-auth/blob/master/vertx-auth-jwt/src/main/java/io/vertx/ext/auth/jwt/impl/JWTUser.java

Comment: I encountered an issue about the vertx-auth repo, can you help me answer here? https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-auth/issues/213

Comment: Paulo Lopes: In my case, I wanted to do the custom authentication where let's say token is static. I extended the JWTAuth class and overriden the generateToken and authenticate methods accordingly. And added the handler with the router. Request is secured but I doesn't validate my static token. Actually it doesn't even go to my custom implementation.

Is it something I am doing wrong? As per your comment @Paulo, Overriding the authenticate method should work for me but no luck.

I haven't found any alternative auth which might fulfil my scenario.